# Click function for AppSidebarNav with SweetAlert

Tags: angular, uinavigationbar, sidebar, sweetalert2, core-ui

[image]

**Scenario**: For example you are in "Option 4" page and want to click "Option 5" page by clicking the side bar. Expected is that there will be a confirmation pop-up saying that there are incomplete fields (exclamation point indicator) in "Option 4".

*By the way this behavior is okay when clicking next and back button. Shown in the image below. This behavior is expected when clicking the side nav bar.
[image]

When I searched for the possible solutions over the internet. I found this article, https://github.com/coreui/coreui-react/issues/79.

I've tried on my end,

```
{
  name: 'Option 4',
  icon: 'icon-target',
  url: `${path}/${PathConstants.Index}/${PathConstants.Option4}`,
  attributes: {onClick:  showConfirmationPopup(validation?.formOption4)}
},
{
  name: 'Option 5',
  icon: 'icon-notebook',
  url: `${path}/${PathConstants.Index}/${PathConstants.Option5}`
}
```

What I want is that when Option 4 (from side nav bar) is clicked it will trigger **showConfirmationPopup()** with a parameter **validation?.formOption4** that checks if the fields in option 4 is complete. If fields are complete no popup will display it will just navigate on option 5, otherwise a pop-up will display.

The logic for **showConfirmationPopup** shown below.

```
function showConfirmationPopup(isComplete: boolean) {

if (!isComplete) {
  NotifUtils.showConfirmMessage('There are incomplete required fields. Are you sure you want to move in the next page?',
  () => { //when "Ok" is clicked from confirmation popup, it will navigate to option 5},
  () => { //when "Cancel" is clicked from confirmation popup, it will not navigate to option 5});
} else {
  //Continue to Navigate
}
}
```

Sweetalert pop-up: https://sweetalert2.github.io/

For this codes, the popup displays but I can't click either the "Okay" / "Cancel" button because the pop-up close automatically. I am stucked on these codes. I want the popup to stay in the UI and let me choose if I want to proceed to next page (option 5) or not if fields from option 4 is incomplete.

Any help you could provide would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. A route guard (CanDeactivate) in Angular can be used in this scenario.
Sample CanDeactivate guard:

```
export class CanDeactivateComponentGuard implements CanDeactivate<MyComponent> {

canDeactivate(component: MyComponent, route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  const name = component.Name;
  const subject = new Subject<boolean>();
  
  if (name === '') {
      NotifUtils.showConfirmMessage(`Proceed? Your name is empty`,
       () => {
        subject.next(true); //call back when "Yes" button is clicked
      }, () => {
        subject.next(false); //call back when "No" button is clicked
      });
      return subject.asObservable();
  };
  return  true;
}
```

This guard/logic can be used on routes with a sweetalert confirmation pop-up.